# X11 ignores preferred mode

Tags: x11, configuration, awesome, lightdm

### Problem

I'm transitioning the configuration of my [multihead](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multihead) monitors from using some rather ugly [scripts](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/tilde/tree/40e5b9ccf42c4991ff6a56d91b57406ac319bbf9/.screenlayout) to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf. My layout has two monitors of 1920x1200, one rotated left. The scripts were able to configure this just fine using the following command:

```
xrandr \
    --output "DP-1" \
        --mode 1920x1200 \
        --pos 1200x360 \
        --rotate normal \
        --primary \
    --output "DP-2" \
        --mode 1920x1200 \
        --pos 0x0 \
        --rotate left
```

I've tried to translate this to configuration:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "DP-1"
    Option "Primary" "true"
    Option "Position" "1200 360"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "DP-2"
    Option "Rotate" "left"
EndSection
```

This unfortunately has the side effect of setting the resolution of the rotated screen to 1600×1200, even though the preferred mode is still 1920×1200:

```
$ xrandr
[…]
DP-2 connected 1200x1600+0+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95 +
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00* 
[…]
```

How can I write configuration which will use the rotated monitor's preferred resolution of 1920x1200?

### Non-solutions

- [Explicitly setting the screen size to fit both monitors](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr#Resolution_lower_than_expected):

  ```
  Section "Screen"
      Driver "radeon"
      SubSection "Display"
          Virtual 3120 1920
      EndSubSection
  EndSection
  ```
- Explicitly setting the preferred mode for DP-2 (`Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1200"`) caused the *other* screen to be reduced to 1600×1200, so that's probably a clue.

### Workaround

Force the resolution by using `xrandr --output DP-2 --mode 1920x1200`.

Comment: If setting the mode via `xrandr` works, did you try setting the mode(line) of DP-2 in xorg.conf? Also, use `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` to debug what the X server actually does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked in the end was to explicitly set the virtual screen size *and* the preferred mode for *both* of the screens:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "DP-1"
    Option "Primary" "true"
    Option "Position" "1200 360"
    Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1200"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "DP-2"
    Option "Rotate" "left"
    Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1200"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Driver "radeon"
    SubSection "Display"
        Virtual 3120 1920
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```